# How to connect the theory of fixed-point numbers and its practical implementation?

Tags: c++, fixed-point

The theory of fixed-point number is that we divide certain number of bits between integer part and fractional part. This amount is fixed.

For example, 26.5 is stored in that order:
[image: power of 2 representation]

---

To convert from floating-point to fixed-point, we follow this algorithm:

- Calculate x = floating_input * 2^(fractional_bits)

  ```
  27.3 * 2^10 = 27955.2
  ```
- Round x to the nearest whole number (e.g. round(x))

  ```
  27955
  ```
- Store the rounded x in an integer container

---

Now if we look on the bit representation of our numbers and on what multiplying on 2^(fractional_bits) makes, we will see:

```
27 is 11011
27*2^10 is 110 1100 0000 0000    which is shifting on 10 bits to the left.
```

So we can say, that multiplying on 2^10 indeed gives us "space" in the right part of bits for save forth altering of this number. We can make two such numbers converted in this way, interacting each other and eventually re-converted to familiar view  with point by opposite dividing on 2^10.

If we recall that bits are stored in some integer variable, which in turn has its own amount of bits it gets clear that as more bits in that variable are devoted for fraction part as less bits remain for integer part of number.

```
27.3 * 2^10 = 27955.2 should be rounded for storing in integer type to
27955 which is 110 1101 0011 0011
```

after that number can be altered somehow, certain value isn't important now, and let's say, we want to retrieve back human-readable value:

```
27955/2^10 = 27,2998046875
```

---

What about amount of bits after point?
Let's say we have two numbers with purpose to multiply them and we chose **10 bits** after point

```
27 * 3.3 = 89.1 expected
27*2^10 = 27 648 is 110 1100 0000 0000
3.3*2^10 = 3 379 is     1101 0011 0011
27 648 * 3 379 = 93 422 592
consequently 
27*3.3 = 93 422 592/(2^10*2^10) = 89.09 pretty accurate
```

Let's take **1 bit** after point

```
27 and 3.3
27*2^1 = 54 is 110110
3.3*2^1 = 6.6 after round 6 is 110
54 * 6 = 324
consequently 
27*3.3 = 324/(2^1*2^1) = 81 which is unsatisfying
```

---

On practice we can use next code to create and operate with fixed-point number:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int scale = 10;

#define DoubleToFixed(x) (x*(double)(1<<scale))
#define FixedToDouble(x) ((double)x / (double)(1<<scale))
#define IntToFixed(x) (x << scale)
#define FixedToInt(x) (x >> scale)
#define MUL(x,y) (((x)*(y)) >> scale)
#define DIV(x,y) ((x) << scale)

int main()
{
double a = 7.27;
double b = 3.0;

int f = DoubleToFixed(a);
cout << f<<endl;                  //7444
cout << FixedToDouble(f)<<endl;   //7.26953125

int g = DoubleToFixed(b);
cout << g<<endl;                  //3072
int c = MUL(f,g);
cout << FixedToDouble(c)<<endl;   //21.80859375

}
```

So, where is connection between the theory of fixed emplacement of point between bits (powers of 2) and practice implementation? If we store fixed-number in int, it is obvious, that there is no place for storing the point in it.

It seems that fixed-point numbers are just conversion for increase performance. And to retrieve human-readable number after calculations, the opposite conversion must present.

I hope, I understand the algorithm. But is the idea of placement of point between digits is just an abstract idea?

Comment: Fixed-point arithmetic has been used in real-world computing for half a century. You might as well talk about the "theory" of binary integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed-point formats are used as a way to represent fractional numbers. Quite commonly, processors perform fixed-point or integer arithmetic faster or more efficiently than floating-point arithmetic. Whether fixed-point arithmetic is suitable for an application depends on what numbers the application needs to work with.

Using fixed-point formats does require converting input to the fixed-point format and converting numbers in the fixed-point format to output. But this is also true of integers and floating-point: All input must be converted to whatever internal format is used to represent it, and all output must be produced by converting from internal formats.

> And how does multiplying on 2^(fractional_bits) affect the quantity of digits after the point?

Suppose we have some number *x* that is represented as an integer *X* = *x*•2<sup>*f*</sup>, where *f* is the number of fraction bits. Conceptually *X* is in a fixed-point format. Similarly, we have *y* represented as *Y* = *y*•2<sup>*f*</sup>.

If we execute an integer multiplication instruction to produce result *Z* = *XY*, then *Z* = *XY* = (*x*•2<sup>*f*</sup>)•(*y*•2<sup>*f*</sup>) = *xy*•2<sup>2*f*</sup>. Then, if we divide *Z* by 2<sup>*f*</sup> (or, nearly equivalently, shift it right by *f* bits), we have *xy*•2<sup>*f*</sup> except for any rounding errors that may have occurred in the division. And *xy*•2<sup>*f*</sup> is the fixed-point representation of the product of *x* and *y*.

Thus, we can effect a fixed-point multiplication by performing an integer multiplication followed by a shift.

Often, to get rounding instead of truncation, a value of half of 2<sup>*f*</sup> is added before the shift, so we compute floor((*XY* + 2<sup>*f*−1</sup>) / 2<sup>*f*</sup>):

- Multiply *X* by *Y*.
- Add 2<sup>*f*−1</sup>.
- Shift right *f* bits.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that fixed-point numbers are just convertion for encreese performance.

You might as well say that floating-point numbers are a conversion to increase the representable range.

Whatever format your numbers are originally coming in as (strings, voltage levels, integers, etc.), you often convert them to floating point numbers in order to store or operate on them, but neither floating point nor fixed point is a human-readable representation.

Floating point numbers have lower precision and a wider magnitude range; fixed point numbers have higher precision and a narrower magnitude range. (Performance differences depend on the architecture and the important operations.) You shouldn't think of the fixed-point representation as a conversion from floating point, but as an alternative to floating point.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a class that wraps an `int` along with the fixed radix point information.  Indeed, the use is implicit, but you then define your own multiplication (for example) that works on the fixed point *meaning* as a whole rather than just multiplying the underlying ints.

You don't want to leave the implicit meaning ... make it known to the compiler in a strong way.  You should not have to explicitly call your handling functions; make it part of the class semantics.